# error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I am using the latest substrate-node-template few weeks back it was building fine.
But the same project isn't building now, I did not do any changes. Error is occurring in runtime interface. I am getting[image] error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types.

PFA screenshot for detail error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please provide specific things you changed, and a MVE

Comment: You can access my repo [link](https://github.com/vjgaur/substrate-proof-of-work) I just added my pow code separately. But even after removing that it gives the same error. I did not add any code in runtime.  Please refer the github repo for code

Answer (score 2):

This means that you are trying to compile `sp-io` or just `sp-runtime-interface` without the `std` enabled. They currently assume that if `std` is not enabled, you are compiling for Wasm. There are checks to ensure that certain assumptions are correct and these checks are failing for you.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this. You are correct. I did not have std crate in  my cargo.toml.  After I added and enabled it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem.

It's due to some std leak somewhere, no_std not being used properly, enabled:

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types --> /home/flipchan/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/fc3fd07/primitives/runtime-interface/src/impls.rs:45:1  45 | assert_eq_size!(usize, u32); | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ | = note: source type: usize (64 bits) = note: target type: u32 (32 bits) = note: this error originates in the macro assert_eq_size (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Have you double checked the no_std flags?

Comment: After adding `std = [... "my-pallet/std", ...]` in Cargo.toml it worked for me as well